# Dokku Postgres Import/Export issues

Tags: postgresql, dokku

I exported a database using `dokku postgres:export dbname` and imported it to another instance using `dokku postgres:import dbname`. The application running on the new instance does not connect correctly to the new imported database. It is connecting to the database itself, but the data is not there. I entered connected to both instances. Running `\l` both were identical. However when I run `\dt` is where the difference is.
Actual Results

```
// On the new instance
=# \dt 
                 List of relations
 Schema |          Name          | Type  |  Owner
--------+------------------------+-------+----------
 public | document               | table | postgres
...

// On the original instance
=# \dt 
                 List of relations
 Schema |          Name          | Type  |  Owner
--------+------------------------+-------+----------
 dbname | document               | table | postgres
...
```

The data was moved over, but is is the public schema (I think). Running select queries gives me different results as well.

```
// Original machine
SELECT * FROM document;
// Returns the data


SELECT * FROM dbname.document;
// Also returns the data


// New machine
SELECT * FROM document;
// Empty result

SELECT * FROM dbname.document;
// Returns the data
```

Expected Results

I guess I would expect that exporting from one db and importing to another with the same name would produce nearly identical instances. Any help here would be great. Everything else is working great in the app, it connects to the db, but returns no data.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this problem I got it working by connecting to the postgres instance by running `dokku postgres:connect dbname` and changing the search_path from `"$user", public` to `dbname, public`. It works for now. However I don't feel like this is the best solution.